Apps targeting Android 12 or later must specify the mutability of PendingIntents with either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE
I have an android app which was running fine one the Play Store. I did a very small change (almost negligible) and was trying to submit the update but suddenly I'm getting the below error while processing the update

We found some common issues that are preventing your app from being sent for review. You must address these issues before you can send your changes for review.
Unspecified PendingIntent mutability
Apps targeting Android 12 or later must specify the mutability of PendingIntents with either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE. Having unspecified mutability may cause your app to crash.
Your app creates a PendingIntent without specifying whether it is mutable in the following place:
androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent
Update your app so it specifies the mutability of PendingIntents.

I didn't update any libraries (all libraries are latest version only) and targeting the latest android version and also I don't have any code in the app which uses the method buildMediaButtonPendingIntent.
By analysing the dependincy tree I found that the androidx.media:media library (which contains the class MediaButtonReceiver) is present in com.facebook.android:facebook-login library which I'm using for Facebook login in my app.
But I doubt if the issue really lies in the facebook-login SDK as I'm using its latest version only. Also, no other dependency in my app includes androidx.media:media library

What version of androidx.media:media does the Gradle dependency report state that you are pulling in? Also, what is the actual version of com.facebook.android:facebook-login are you using?

@CommonsWare androidx.media:media:1.0.0 and com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release -> 17.0.2

You are pulling in androidx.media:media:1.0.0. That is from 2019, well before this Android change came to pass.
The latest is 1.7.0. You might try adding a dependency on that. Or, if you are also using Facebook's SDK, perhaps you are on an old version of it, as they claim to have fixed this issue years ago.
